# Add objects to List of Long

Tags: java, list, long-integer

I want to add a Long Object to a List of Long, but I get some error that I don't understand

I have the following minimal example:

```
package main;

import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Long> LongList = List.of((long) 3);
        LongList.add((long) 2);
    }

}
```

The Error msg is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
> at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)
> at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.add(ImmutableCollections.java:147)
> at main.Test.main(Test.java:10)

I need to have the format Long, and I tried to change the way I convert to long. Also, I tried to give the position for where to add explicitly, but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `List.of` carefully?

Comment: Oh dang. Thank you.... The List.of wasn't necessary... I just use an array List. I completely overlooked the obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation of `List::of` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E)):

> Returns an unmodifiable list containing one element. See [Unmodifiable Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) for details.

This is why the call to `add(...)` results in an `UnsupportedOperationException`. If we want to modify the list created, we will have to create a modifiable list, e.g.:

```
List<Long> LongList = new ArrayList<>(List.of((long) 3));
LongList.add((long) 2);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/i80Qmo)

or:

```
List<Long> LongList = new ArrayList<>();
LongList.add((long) 3);
LongList.add((long) 2);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/sB7Ioq)

---

Some remarks on the code:

- Variable names should be written in `lowerCamelCase`, not `UpperCamelCase` (`LongList` -> `longList`)
- Instead of casting the literals `2` and `3` to `long`, we can use the `long`-literals `2L` and `3L`

Comment: Thank you :) I'm just learning to code, so your feedback is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the list variable with the *List.of()* method. That's why your list is immutable. No items can be added to it. This can also be seen in the error message.

Please initialize the variable with a new instance of ArrayList. Then you can start adding items to it.

```
List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<>():
longList.add(3L);
longList.add(2L);
```